# Match each of three exact phases from two different supplies (distribution boxes)

Tags: wiring, three-phase

I have to replace 3 phase cable powering refrigeration unit from one distribution box to another.

For refrigeration compressor is required to preserve same phase sequence.
Unfortunately, I don't have fancy multimeter with functionality to detect phase sequence.
And I don't want to rely on conductors' insulation color.

The question is: if I will measure voltage between phases from both distribution boxes and will get on some pair of conductors close to zero reading (or at least significantly lower than other readings) - that means this pair of wires has the same phase?
(Does phases from different electricity supplies are synchronized?)

Comment: _"And I don't want to rely on conductors' insulation color."_ Why not? If not, you need to either follow each conductor, measure which one is which or simply get yourself a fancy multimeter which can measure phase order.

Comment: I believe not all electrician are following proper color coding for 3 phase wiring. Mulimeter with such functionality is quiet expensive for single time job.

Comment: No legal requirement on wiring in the country where you reside? Just connect and see if it runs backwards? If yes, shift L2 and L3?

Comment: "I believe not all electrician are following proper color coding for 3 phase wiring." As you're replacing a run of cable you can note the colour codes at each end of the cable. It's extremely unlikely the colours change mid-cable but you can check for that with the continuity feature on a DMM. If you're working with 3Φ equipment that's sensitive to phase reversal you ought to use a phase sequence (or rotation) tester. Alternatively you could get an industrial electrician with the correct equipment to either carry out the work or check yours.

Comment: You have no frame of reference for using a DMM.  Ultimately, you are not concerned about phase X being connected to phase X on the box.  You are concerned that the phase sequence XYZ is the reverse of XZY, which means different rotation.  Connect it up one way and see if the device works (compressor spins in the correct direction).  If not reverse two phases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the supply source to the two distribution boxes is the same this will work. Your line 3 phase supply will be synchronized across boxes.

Line electricity from different suppliers is almost certainly synchronized, if the suppliers have a feed into the overall distribution grid they must be.

If one of the boxes is supplied from a separate supply, say a generator at the time of testing it will not work.

Comment: Both distribution boxes are inside same building but electricity supplied by different electricity companies. I am 80% sure they are connected to the same transformer. I will see it when i come to location and check.

Comment: Answer edited to address this,

Comment: Just checked voltage between wires and noticed then i have Brown to Black = 0V, Black to Grey = 0V, Grey to Brown = 0V. In all other cases - 420V. That means there is one phase shift but phases are in same order, what actually i was worrying about.